# Convert short-code to YouTube link in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, youtube, amp-html

I Need to convert this Shortcode:

```
[youtube id="ElWkGqhoDfE" width="720" height="380"]
```

to Youtube Link like

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ElWkGqhoDfE
```

So, I need to convert it when page load in WordPress AMP

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this function

```
function get_shortcode($code){
if (strpos($code, 'youtube') !== false) {
    $youtube = explode(" ", $code);
    $youId = str_replace('"', "" ,str_replace('id="', "", $youtube[1]));
    $link = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v='.$youId ;
    return $link;
}
}
$shortcode = '[youtube id="ElWkGqhoDfE" width="720" height="380"]' ;
echo get_shortcode($shortcode);
```

Comment: thank ,,, but the shortcode in content ,, how can check in content

Comment: can you please send me content. And you can use preg_match function to find shortcode

Answer (score 0):

Check If it works,
Simply do

```
$shortcode = do_shortcode('[youtube id="ElWkGqhoDfE" width="720" height="380"]'); 
echo $shortcode;
```

now $shortcode is available for further use

Comment: Obviously you did not understand my request, I wanted to convert the Shortcode, to the link without use any shortcode

Comment: Simply do 
`$shortcode = do_shortcode('[youtube id="ElWkGqhoDfE" width="720" height="380"]');
echo $shortcode;`

Comment: @sunil's answer is the correct way then, please rephrase the question to
"WordPress: convert short-code extracted from page content to YouTube link"